# Swift 2.0 NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: xcode, nsurlconnection, swift2, nsurlrequest, reachability

I am using the code below to check for an internet connection. It was working correctly but after the Swift 2.0 update I now see an error on the line `var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: nil) as NSData?` saying extra argument 'error' in call.

```
class func isConnectedToNetwork()->Bool{

    var Status:Bool = false
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    request.timeoutInterval = 10.0

    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: nil) as NSData?

    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            Status = true
        }
    }

    return Status
}
```

Do you have any ideas what I should change it to? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you look at apples documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:) you'll see that the definition changed to this:

```
class func sendSynchronousRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest,
            returningResponse response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>) throws -> NSData
```

They have removed the error parameter and the method throws now an `ErrorType`, if the request fails. So this should work:

```
do {
    let data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
} catch (let e) {
    print(e)
}
```

However you shouldn't use this method: It's deprecated in favor of `NSURLSession` since iOS 9 and OS X 10.11.

Comment: Thank you. What should I be using instead for iOS 9?

Comment: NSURLSession has replaced it officially now.