# Extra argument 'error' in call. (Swift 2.0)

Tags: swift2

Can anywone convert this into Swift 2.0?
var result = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request!, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
I have aslo &error line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2.0 NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668554/swift-2-0-nsurlconnection-sendsynchronousrequest)

Comment: My line it's slightly different

Comment: As said in the link, you shouldn't use this method anymore anyway. But if you really *need* (not *want*) to use it, then you'll have to explain in your question what is specific to your code that isn't fixable by taking example from the link we've given to you (or any other example from the many already existing on SO). Thanks.

Comment: This is RSSObject.swift: http://pastebin.com/qDcsYQBi

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.0 introduces [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508) syntax, which is what you now have to use for methods that used to take an error parameter.