# Use of unresolved identifier 'NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy' In swift 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2, http-status-code-404, nsurlrequest

I have converted Check validation of NSURL from objective-c to swift 2 but couldn't figure out how to fix : `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy'` error and also :

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSHTTPURLResponse' to expected argument type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>' (aka 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<NSURLResponse>>')
```

what's the right synatx for below code in swift 2 : 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Swift versions of enums tend to not have the prefix and start with a `.` if the enum type can be inferred.

If you type a `.`, you often can get autocomplete for the choices.

In the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestCachePolicy

You can see that the Swift version of the enum is:

```
enum NSURLRequestCachePolicy : UInt {
    case UseProtocolCachePolicy
    case ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    case ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    static var ReloadIgnoringCacheData: NSURLRequestCachePolicy { get }
    case ReturnCacheDataElseLoad
    case ReturnCacheDataDontLoad
    case ReloadRevalidatingCacheData
}
```

So you would want `.UseProtocolCachePolicy`

Your second problem is addressed in this other SO question/answer:

[Swift 2.0 NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668554/swift-2-0-nsurlconnection-sendsynchronousrequest)